# How to send a transaction for native assets via cardano-wallet CLI

Tags: wallet

To send ada with cardano-wallet cli, you can do

```
cardano-wallet transaction create <WALLET_ID> --payment <AMOUNT>@<ADDRESS>
```

But there is no documentation on how to send native assets.

Answer (score 0):

Please refere this API documentation for cardano-wallet https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/constructTransaction
The

```
{
  "transaction": "string",
  "coin_selection": {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "address": "addr1sjck9mdmfyhzvjhydcjllgj9vjvl522w0573ncustrrr2rg7h9azg4cyqd36yyd48t5ut72hgld0fg2xfvz82xgwh7wal6g2xt8n996s3xvu5g",
        "amount": {
          "quantity": 42000000,
          "unit": "lovelace"
        },
        "assets": [
          {
            "policy_id": "65ab82542b0ca20391caaf66a4d4d7897d281f9c136cd3513136945b",
            "asset_name": "",
            "quantity": 0
          }
        ],
        "id": "1423856bc91c49e928f6f30f4e8d665d53eb4ab6028bd0ac971809d514c92db1",
        "derivation_path": [
          "1852H"
        ],
        "index": 0
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "address": "addr1sjck9mdmfyhzvjhydcjllgj9vjvl522w0573ncustrrr2rg7h9azg4cyqd36yyd48t5ut72hgld0fg2xfvz82xgwh7wal6g2xt8n996s3xvu5g",
        "amount": {
          "quantity": 42000000,
          "unit": "lovelace"
        },
        "assets": [
          {
            "policy_id": "65ab82542b0ca20391caaf66a4d4d7897d281f9c136cd3513136945b",
            "asset_name": "",
            "quantity": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],...
```

In the above example given on the page, the native assets are included in the transactions.

Comment: it is for the REST api, right? As far as I understand, cli is a wrapper on top of the api. But it is unclear how to do the same from cardano-wallet cli
with `cardano-cli`, you can do
`cardano-cli  transaction build --tx-out <ADDRESS>+<AMOUNT>+"<TOKEN_AMOUNT> <POLICY_ID>.<TOKEN_NAME>"`

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to do it with the cli